# Retromod: stuck with shifter replacement, which ones would work?

Tags: shimano, shifter, restoration

Retromoding a beautiful 1992 marin with fantastic original color scheme. Adding a disc fork and disc brake at the front. Rear is 7 speed xt (also have spares dx and lx 7 speeds).

Issue is that shifters are integrated to brake levers. Now I have a new brake lever with modern I spec.

What shifters would go on those 7 speed whilst not requiring to be mounted on old can't brake levers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to replace the integrated shifters with separate shifter and brake controls.

If you're American or similar, the front brake will be on the left side so you need a left hydraulic brake lever and a separate 3 or 2by shifter, and can keep using the existing right combination brifter.

For other locations in the world where the front brake is on the right-hand, you need a right hand hydraulic brake lever and a separate 7 position shifter.   Such 7 speed shifters are common and cheap in different styles.

Hydraulic levers are "handed" and generally cannot be flipped over.

It sounds like the looks are important, so try and match the levers for appearance, or consider adding brake lever covers to disguise differences.   Paint tends to not stick well regardless of the prep-work.

For shifters, there's no need to keep them similar.  I have a bike with a friction front shifter and a completely different trigger shifter for the rear.

Comment: Spot on Criggie this is what I'm facing right now. I guess the question is can I buy any modern 7 speed (only Alivio now, struggling to find any higher end 7 speed?!) to work with those 90s Lx / Xt derailleurs? Or do I need a standalone 7 speed shifter from back in the days?

Comment: "Elsewhere the opposite" careful with that part, it's not quite the case in my experience

Comment: @njzk2 thanks - clarified.

Comment: @tweedi "7 speed" is 7 speed.  There was no distinction between the dimensions and pull ratios back then.  The higher groupsets just had better build quality, more aluminium and less steel or plastic.   On the other hand, a modern low-groupset tourney part that works now is more use than a bike with no shifter.